# Using Codeigniter Escape function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have recently added a comments section to a blog.  Codeigniter says to always escape data before putting it into the Db.(I do have xss clean on fulltime). Some people say all active record operations are escaped.  Am I wasting my time using escape on the function below?

Using the function below I escape the data, but it all comes out into the view escaped.  How do you "un-escape" data so it will be readable without the ' '?  I dont want to use a regex to delete every '' in case its used in a sentence

I guess my real question is, are active records always escaped or not?

ie: Author comes out 'Name'

```
 function comment_insert()
{
$data = array
(
    'entry_id' => $this->db->escape($this->input->post('entry_id')),
    'ip' => $this->db->escape($this->input->post('ip')),
    'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
    'comment' => $this->db->escape($this->input->post('comment')),
    'author' => $this->db->escape($this->input->post('author')),
    'email' => $this->db->escape($this->input->post('email'))
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules('ip', 'IP', 'required|trim|valid_ip');//check
$this->form_validation->set_rules('entry_id', 'Entry ID', 'required|trim|numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment',   'required|trim|max_length[600]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Name',  'required|trim|alpha_dash');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
{
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->insert('comments', $data);
    redirect('main/blog_view/'.$_POST['entry_id']);
} else 
{
   redirect('main/blog_view/'.$_POST['entry_id']);
}   
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the CodeIgniter User guide for the Active Record functions in the Database Class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

> Beyond simplicity, a major benefit to using the Active Record features is that it allows you to create database independent applications, since the query syntax is generated by each database adapter. *It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system.* (emphasis added)

So yes, you're wasting your time. As long as you use Active Record, your data are automatically escaped.

Comment: Thnak you.  Once you start reading and see things like this
($this-db->where())
"Note: All values passed to this function are escaped automatically, producing safer queries."

its easy to forget that it is escaped anyways.
I appreciate your answer

Comment: It has to be noted that for complex sql queries its not always possible to use active records methods , especially when we are referring more than one table and have sub queries within the query.