# Escape string in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql-real-escape-string

Is there any function in codeigniter similar to

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

I have tried `$this->db->escape()` but no luck

below code works

```
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string($request['3']);  // O'relley-max
```

but other CI method not working any suggestion. I need to know what CI method escaping string for a variable

I know if you use validation rules `xss_clean` it workes but i don't want to apply rules

Comment: check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3358603/270037

Comment: i have checked and searched i want to know if there any similar function?

Comment: No. It is not me. what are you getting for `$this->db->escape()`?

Comment: db query fails error?

Comment: @kumar_v   WHERE a.a_lname = ".$this->db->escape($surname)." works but i need to escape variable there it's not working

Comment: can you show your full query? I mean last executed query.

Comment: check $sql = "SELECT $selectField FROM applications a JOIN users u ON u.a_id = a.a_id WHERE a.a_lname = '$surname' AND a.a_dob = '$dob' AND a.a_add1_postcode = '$postcode' limit 0,1";

Comment: Are you getting this query for `$this->db->last_query();`?

Comment: please edit my answer if you can add any for this

Answer (score 3):

You can add a parameter

```
$this->input->post('item',true)
```

To avoid any script and it add up extra security to the input value
its avoids the xss scripting check the above link for proper documentation

[Check for details](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)